# Using sed to add character

Tags: regex, perl, sed, cygwin

I am working on adding a character at the end of a line for a large file.  Each line has 3 octets of an IP network, ending in a period and a line feed (\n).  I am working in cygwin.

i.e.

10.23.34.

23.34.45.

I am attempting to use `sed` to do the work for me; I've tried the following two commands with no success:

```
sed 's/\n/1\n/' <filename>

sed 's/\n/1\n/g' <filename>

sed 's/(.*)/${1}1/' <filename>
```

I have gotten it to work in perl with `perl -pe 's/(.*\.)/${1}1/' <filename>`

What am I doing wrong please?

Thank you

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is 10.23.34.1, 23.34.45.1, etc.  Just appending a 1 to the end of each line that is already in a X.Y.Z. format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `foo` at the end of every line:

```
sed 's/$/foo/' filename > new_filename
```

Replace in place:

```
sed -i 's/$/foo/' filename
```

Comment: Thank you!!  I can't believe I didn't realize I could just use a s/$/1 to do that.

Comment: `$` represents enf of line.

Answer (score 0):

sed works by default line by line (so no New line at the end)

```
sed 's/$/1/' YourFile
```

do your trick but without any chekc (ALL line MUST have the 3 octet start of an IP ended by a dot ), maybe som little check is usefull

```
sed '/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\} *$/ s/ *$/1/'
```

verify that the line ended with 3 number (1 to 3 digit),each separated by a dot and eventually some trailing space. add your `1` and remove trailing space in this case.